# If you bcc yourself to a campaign with over 500k audience in Journey Builder would I receive 500k emails?

Tags: journeybuilder

If I wanted to bcc my email to a journey would I essentially get a copy of every email I sent in the journey relating to that email I bcc'd?  For example, would I receive 500,000 emails if I bcc: my email to the email i'm sending to my subscribers? I'm trying to find the best way to attach a send list to a campaign journey.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you would receive 500k messages and consume 1M Super messages

Refer to this [help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_select_audience.htm&type=5)

> If you enter plain text email addresses, each email address copies to every email sent to the targeted audience. For example, if you send to a targeted audience that contains 1,000 subscribers, 1,000 emails are sent to each CC and BCC recipient, in addition to the 1,000 emails sent to the targeted subscribers. For example, if a send goes out to 1,000 subscribers, with 1 CCed email address, 2,000 emails of your subscription would be used.